# Issues with advance search in Java NetBeans

Tags: java

I'm having some issues with an advanced search in Java NetBeans. The code for that particular area was not made by me but I'm trying to correct it. The `clieninput`, `productinput` and `truckinput` are not working properly. They do not find anything or some show only a few records.

The other 2 are working properly, one is only numbers and the other one is date, does that have to do with anything?

The code for that part is:

```
private void generarButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        model.getRows().clear();
        String sql = "SELECT id_scale_load, ticket_number, customer_code, customer_name, product_code, " +
                "product_name, truck_code, truck_name, tagid, tare, gross, (gross - tare) " +
                "AS net, ash, btu, mustuire, sulfur, fin FROM scale_load " +
                "WHERE (ticket_number = ? OR ? = true)AND(customer_name LIKE ? OR ? = true) " +
                "AND (date(fin) = ? OR ? = true) AND(product_name LIKE ? OR ? = true) " +
                "AND(truck_code LIKE ? OR > ? = true) ";

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        if (!ticketInput.getText().isEmpty()) {
            pst.setString(1, ticketInput.getText());
            pst.setBoolean(2, false);
        } else {
            pst.setString(1, "");
            pst.setBoolean(2, true);
        }

        if (!clientInput.getText().isEmpty()) {
            pst.setString(3, "'" + clientInput.getText() + "'");
            pst.setBoolean(4, false);
        } else {
            pst.setString(3, "");
            pst.setBoolean(4, true);
        }

        if (dateInput.getDate() != null) {
            pst.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(dateInput.getDate().getTime()));
            pst.setBoolean(6, false);
        } else {
            pst.setString(5, null);
            pst.setBoolean(6, true);
        }

        if (!productInput.getText().isEmpty()) {
            pst.setString(7, "'" + productInput.getText() + "%'");
            pst.setBoolean(8, false);
        } else {
            pst.setString(7, "");
            pst.setBoolean(8, true);
        }

        if (!truckInput.getText().isEmpty()) {
            pst.setString(9, "'" + truckInput.getText() + "%'");
            pst.setBoolean(10, false);
        } else {
            pst.setString(9, "");
            pst.setBoolean(10, true);
        }
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        printButton.setEnabled(true);

        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Ticket row = new Ticket();
            row.setNo(rs.getInt(1));
            row.setTicket(rs.getInt(2));
            row.setCustomerCode(rs.getString(3));
            row.setCustomerName(rs.getString(4));
            row.setProductCode(rs.getString(5));
            row.setProductName(rs.getString(6));
            row.setTruckCode(rs.getString(7));
            row.setTruckName(rs.getString(8));
            row.setTagID(rs.getString(9));
            row.setGross(rs.getInt(10));
            row.setTare(rs.getInt(11));
            row.setNet(rs.getInt(12));
            row.setAsh(rs.getDouble(13));
            row.setBtu(rs.getInt(14));
            row.setMustuire(rs.getDouble(15));
            row.setSulfure(rs.getDouble(16));
            row.setDate(new Date(rs.getDate(17).getTime()));
            model.addRow(row);
        }
        model.refresh();
        //ticketInput.setText("");
        printTicketButton.setEnabled(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
}
```

Is there a mistake in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give much information, but something that looks wrong:  When you provide a query parameter you single-quote it, but when you don't provide a parameter you use "", I believe this should result in a SQL syntax error

The version with a supplied value will create a (correct) line that looks like this:

```
(product_name LIKE 'Product' OR false = true)
```

vs not supplying a line which should create a line like this:

```
(product_name LIKE OR true = true)
                  ^ SQL Wants something here, even if true=true!
```

Shouldn't the second one be a problem?  Try defaulting it to " ' ' " instead of "" to get:

```
(product_name LIKE '' OR true = true)
```

Comment: Hello Bill K
It actually worked with something you suggested. I tried this: 
if (!clientInput.getText().isEmpty()) {

            pst.setString(3, "" + clientInput.getText() + "");  <--------

            pst.setBoolean(4, false);

Removing the simple comas.
Thank you very much for your time